# How can I write R function to reverse complementary DNA?

Tags: r

```
ReverseFunc <- function(base) {
  if(base == 'A' | base ==  'a') print("T") 
  else(base == 'T' | base == 't') print("A")
  else(base == 'G' | base == 'g') print("C")
  else(base == 'C' | base == 'c') print("G")
}

base <- 'ATCG' #This is your test data
comseq <- ReverseFunc(base)
print(comseq)
```

It does not work. And I have to write the function by do not use a function from an R package.

Answer (score 3):

There's a little known but powerful base R function to do this: `chartr`

```
chartr(old="ATGC", new="TACG", x )

base <- 'ATCG'
chartr("ATGC", "TACG", base )
#[1] "TAGC"
```

To get the lower case items converted just add them as another "old"sequence with the same capitalized sequence as "new" values:

```
chartr("ATGCatgc", "TACGTACG", base )
```

Seems pretty obvious how to use that as the body of a new function and it might be homework so I'm leaving it as "an exercise for the reader."  The error that prevented your version from working was two-fold. 1) using `if` and 2) assuming that the `base` string would be handled character-wise. In R the `if` function does not accept a sequence of arguments so even if you had broken the input character value into its component letters, it would only have processed the first letter. And now I see the final portion of you homework problem. I'd have to argue that the meaning of "not use a function from an R package." does not apply here because `chartr` is in the base installation. The instructor cannot possibly mean that base installation functions cannot be used since even the `function` function would be proscribed in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your function:

1. Your function assumes that the parameter — `base` — is a *single* base (or a vector of bases) rather than a character string which is a concatenation of bases. You’ll first need to split your string, and you need to use `ifelse` instead of `if` to perform vectorised comparisons.
2. For alternative branches you need `else if` instead of just `else`.
3. Your function attempts to output the resulting base via `print`. This isn’t appropriate. Instead, you need to *return* the base.
4. Lastly, this function attempts to compute a complement, but it does not reverse it, despite its name. (The name is also questionable: It should be `ReverseComp` or some variation thereof, and `Func` has no place in the name of a function: it’s redundant and uninformative.)

Put together, we’re left with this:

```
reverse_complement <- function (dna) {
    bases = toupper(strsplit(dna, '')[[1L]])
    compl = ifelse(bases == 'A', 'T',
        ifelse(bases == 'C', 'G',
        ifelse(bases == 'G', 'C',
        ifelse(bases == 'T', 'A', 'N'))))

    paste(rev(compl), collapse = '')
}
```

… however, this nested `ifelse` call is fairly convoluted. The `chartr` solution in the other answer makes this much more readable, and also more efficient. There are other possible solutions (e.g. using `switch`) but they’re not much better either. Short of `chartr`, I’d use a lookup table with `match`.

Comment: @BowornpolNu-im  There's much to be learned in Konrad's improvements and he's listed 4 of them. I would add that the construction strsplit( )[[1]] is something you should study. The `strsplit` function is very powerful and returns it's results in a list of atomic vectors, so you need to be ready to pull out one of them or handle the result with list capable functions.  Agree that a `match` based-function might look fairly compact and might satisfy your instructor better than using `chartr` which I wonder if your instructor even knew about.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a separate answer (and again not offering a complete answer since it's homework). Based on Konrad's suggestion of `match` one could align an input to output translation thusly:

```
c("T","A","C","G","T","A","C","G")[ match( strsplit(base, "")[[1]], 
c("A","T","G","C","a","t","g","c")) ]
#[1] "T" "A" "G" "C"
```

And using `toupper` would make it even more compact:

```
c("T","A","C","G")[ match( toupper(strsplit(base, "")[[1]]), 
c("A","T","G","C")) ]
[1] "T" "A" "G" "C"
```

The lesson to be learned here is that match is designed to retrun a numeric index that is typically then used as an argument to the extraction function `[` to pull out items from a result vector in use cases like

```
  possible_results_to_choose[ match( input, choices) ]
```